# Ionic -> Scroll header together with content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic framework to develop an app.

I have an abstract state, with some html as "header" and an ion-nav-view. This is the template:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item range">
      <i class="icon ion-volume-low"></i>
      <input type="range" name="volume">
    </div>
</div>

<ion-nav-view name="lesson-content"></ion-nav-view>
```

It works fine, but the div with list class it's fixed on the top, I want it to scroll together with the content of ion-nav-view.

If I try to wrap them on ion-content, the content of ion-nav-view gets cropped.

[image: example]

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the header from the index.html and add a custom header inside the ion-view. Works for me